# My app's slogan is not changing on Play Store Search

Tags: android, google-play

I've an application on Google Play Store. My app's slogan was XXX, and now it is YYY for a long time. But when search with my App name, it displays App Name : XXX not YYY. When I navigate from search result, it displays correct slogan which is YYY. Where can I change this? I feel like this slogan is cached by Play Store search.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should receive a notification in the Google Play Console when your change is live, which might take hours.
Play Store app does some caching as well, but from my experience killing and relaunching Play Store should give the latest store listing content.

Comment: The problem is different. This app is live for more than 4 years. In a year ago, I've changed app slogan. But when I search from play.google.com with my app name, on autocomplete, I see old slogan. But after clicking to old slogan, my app is being shown with new slogan. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link https://play.google.com/apps/publish and go to settings, there you can find your developer profile and review it. Hope this might help

Comment: Already checked. I see correct description there. Search auto complete should display updated description. But it doesn't.